# change file names of swift package files

Tags: swift, git, github, swift-package-manager

I have a swift package similar to the example below, and its associated with a git repo both locally and remotely on Github.

```
-ProjectName
    -Sources
    -ProjectName.xcodeproj
    -ProjectNameTestsFolder
        -ProjectNameTests.swift
    -Package.swift
```

From experience, I get nervous before I change any file names associated with a git repo because I have had issues in the past. I would normally try first and then ask if I couldn't figure it out but I don't want to try something and do irreversible damage.

Any recommendations on how I can go about changing all file names associated with ProjectName above locally? Other than the xcodeproj which I know is a little more work, can I just rename the files and commit them for the changes to take effect or is there something else I need to do as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are careful to only "move" files in source control, you shouldn't do anything irreversible.

In my opinion, the best way to rename is:

1. Rename the files on the command line using "git mv" (to ensure changes are tracked). This should get you to a point where SwiftPM is happy with the layout (I assume what you are renaming to handle is the convention for `Tests`).
2. In Xcode, your sources will now show up as red. To fix this, assuming you have a single Xcode group for "ProjectNameTestsFolder", then select that item in the group navigator (Cmd-1), then in the File Inspector (Cmd-Opt-1) change the group path to be the new location. Now the source references should change back to black, and all is well.